# Controlling an object orbiting a sphere

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, orbital-mechanics

I want to let the user control an object moving over the surface of a static sphere. Using two buttons to rotate the direction of the object clockwise and anti-clockwise as it constantly moves forward similar to asteroids.

In scene kit there are three different orientation properties for an SCNNode and I really don't know where to start. I understand how to execute everything except the rotation around the sphere.

Comment: Is the `position` property of `SCNNode` not what you're looking for?

Comment: Well it needs to stay on the surface of the sphere as if it is orbiting so I guess I could use a formula to calculate the position on the surface of a sphere.

Comment: Ah OK, I understand now.  In my answer below I describe a formula for converting spherical coordinates to rectangular coordinates.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for a parameterization of the surface of the sphere.  You can find this online (but it can be tricky if you don't know the magic words to enter for your searches).  Check out the entry on [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere.html).

The surface of the sphere is parameterized by two angle variables, call them `s` and `t`.  Note that one variable will run from zero to 2 pi, and the other will run only from zero to pi.  This is a gotcha that can be easy to miss.  To convert these angles to rectangular (x, y, z) coordinates, you use the formula:

```
x = r cos(s) sin(t)
y = r sin(s) sin(t) // Yes it's sin(t) twice, that's not a typo.
z = r cos(t)
```

I find the following visualization helpful.  A curve in a plane (the xy-plane, for example) sweeps out an angle from zero to pi, half a rotation and corresponds to the parameter `s`.  If you set `t` equal to pi/2, so sin(t) = 1, then you can see how x and y turn into standard rectangular coordinates for a circular section.  After the `s` parameter sweeps out half a circle, you can rotate that half circle *all the way around* from zero to 2 pi, to form a full sphere, and that full sweep corresponds to the parameter `t`.

If you represent your object's position by coordinates `(s, t)` then you can, for the most part, safely convert to rectangular coordinates using the formula above without worrying about the domain of either parameter; however if `s` or `t` grow without bound (say, because your object orbits continuously for a long time) it might be worth the small extra effort to normalize the parameters.  I'm not sure how `sin` or `cos` behave for very large inputs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the in-depth answer! Hmm so if I have my object's direction an angle between 0 and 2 pi how would I break that into my components s and t in order to say move it one degree over the sphere's surface in its current direction? Also if I want the camera to always look along the vector going from the centre of the sphere through the orbiting object in order to keep everything centered is there an easy method for doing that?

Comment: Okay that makes sense. And seeing as both s and t are clamped between different values is there a good way to decide which should act as which component or is it arbitrary? Thank you though, very helpful!

Comment: @jctwood: The parameter that you pass to `sin` in two of the three coordinates is the one that should run from 0 to 2 pi.

Comment: Okay great. I will implement this in the morning but you have resolved my issue in my head anyway!